# Nested for loop in nodejs seems to be running asynchronously

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

So I have two for loops, and one is nested inside another but the results they return seem to be running the first loop and returning its results than the nested loop. How could I make it run in a synchronous behavior? 
For example, all the topicData gets printed in a row instead of printing one topicData and moving on to the nested for loop.
I'm not sure if this is the proper way to implement the async await. Any pointers would be appreciated. Thanks

```
exports.create = (event, context, callback) => {

  var topicTimestamp = "";
  var endpoint = "";

  sns.listTopics(async function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err, err.stack);
    } else {
      console.log(data);
      for (var topic in data.Topics){ //first loop
        //var topicData = "";
        //retrieve each topic and append to topicList if it is lakeview topic
        var topicData =  await data.Topics[topic].TopicArn;
        topicTimestamp = topicData.slice(22, 34); //get only the topic createdAt

        var params = {
          TopicArn: topicData //topicData
        };
        console.log("SUBS per" + params.TopicArn);

        //retrieve subscriptions attached to each topic
        sns.listSubscriptionsByTopic(params, async function(err, subscriptionData){
          console.log(subscriptionData);
          //console.log("SUBS per" + params.TopicArn);
          if (err) {
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
          } else  {
            var endpointList = [];
            for (var sub in subscriptionData.Subscriptions) { //nested loop

              endpoint = await subscriptionData.Subscriptions[sub].Endpoint;

              console.log("ENDPOINT:: " + endpoint);
              endpointList.push(endpoint);
            }
          } // end of else listSub

          //put topic info into table
          var topicsParams = {
            TableName: tableName,
            Item: {
              id: uuidv4(),
              createdAt: timestamp,
              topicCreatedAt: topicTimestamp,
              topic: topicData,
              phoneNumbers: endpointList
            },
          };

          endpointList = [];  //reset to empty array

          dynamoDb.put(topicsParams, (error) => {...}
```

Comment: Use a promise interface (or create a promise wrapper if a promise interface doesn't already exist) for all your asynchronous operations and use `await` with those promises.  That will let you sequence `for` loops with asynchronous operations.  It will also make error handling much cleaner (which you don't really do a proper job of at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues here

- You are trying to do callback style code in loops while you have promise methods available.
- You could also do things in parallel using `promise.all`
- Because of callback style the code is very complicated
- You are awaiting where it is not required. For example in the callback

You can try to use this way

```
exports.create = async (event, context, callback) => {

  try {
    let topicTimestamp = "";
    let endpoint = "";
    const data = await sns.listTopics().promise();
    // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
    for (const topic in data.Topics) { // first loop
    // var topicData = "";
    // retrieve each topic and append to topicList if it is lakeview topic
      const topicData = data.Topics[topic].TopicArn;
      topicTimestamp = topicData.slice(22, 34); // get only the topic createdAt

      const params = {
        "TopicArn": topicData // topicData
      };
      console.log(`SUBS per${ params.TopicArn}`);

      const subscriptionData = await sns.listSubscriptionsByTopic(params).promise();
      const endpointList = [];
      // eslint-disable-next-line guard-for-in
      for (const sub in subscriptionData.Subscriptions) { // nested loop
        endpoint = subscriptionData.Subscriptions[sub].Endpoint;
        console.log(`ENDPOINT:: ${ endpoint}`);
        endpointList.push(endpoint);
      }

      // put topic info into table
      const topicsParams = {
        "TableName": tableName,
        "Item": {
          "id": uuidv4(),
          "createdAt": timestamp,
          "topicCreatedAt": topicTimestamp,
          "topic": topicData,
          "phoneNumbers": endpointList
        }
      };

      // Similarly use dynamodb .promise functions here
    }
  } catch (Err) {
    console.log(Err);
  }
};
```

`aws-sdk` by default supports callback style. To convert them to promise you need to add `.promise()` at end.

At the moment this example is using for loop but you could do the same thing using `Promise.all` as well.

Hope this helps.